# Javascript Can't change object properties in Safari

Tags: javascript, angularjs, safari, web-sql

I'm currently writing an angular app. I've got a bit of code which gets data from websql. Currently all the boolean values inside the object are set as strings. So when I retrieve the data, I do a quick check like so..

```
if(results.completed === "false"){
    results.completed = false;
}else{
    results.completed = true;
}
```

For some odd reason, this works fine on chrome, but when I test it on Safari. The values are unchanged. My full code is below:

```
RecordsService.questions($routeParams.recordId).then(function(results){
    if(results.completed === "false"){
        results.completed = false;
    }else{
        results.completed = true;
    }

    RecordsService.getConsent($rootScope.userData.cui, results.record_id).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
        results.consent = data;
        $scope.questionnaire = results;
    });

    angular.forEach(results.questions, function(question){
        if(question.answer === "null"){question.answer = null;}else{answered++;}
        question.answerOptions = JSON.parse(question.answerOptions);
        $scope.questions.push(question);
    });

    $scope.progress = (answered/$scope.questions.length)*100;

});
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Why not just use `if(results.completed == "false")`? (double equals, as opposed to triple equals)

Comment: tried that. still doesn't work.

Comment: can you try quick easy check with jsFiddle or plunker and add link here.

Comment: You could `results.completed = !results.completed;` and skip the if.

Comment: @skubski, why? OP not change `results.completed` to opposite, just "convert"  string to bool

Comment: Which is exactly what the if is doing... type conversion. Where does operator precedence come into place according to you? xD @Grundy

Comment: @skubski, can you explain what you mean? :-) in your logic you get `!"false" === !"true" === false`, but OP want `"false" === false, and "true"===true`

Comment: @Grundy I ment to use type conversion on the place where this boolean value is needed, instead of manually converting it.

Comment: @skubski, so how you want convert `"false" to false`? and `"true" to true`

Comment: Actually there is a negation missing in my first post. Either way it won't work as I originally thought it would, as the amount of characters seems to be of importance instead of the content when converting. I still don't see why operator precedence is of any importance when using double negation in my fruitless attempt. `result.completed = (result.test === 'true');` should do what I intended to do with !!. Thanks for pointing it out. @Grundy